# Rails ActiveStorage Images not appearing for custom domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, digital-ocean, rails-activestorage

ok this is weird..

I have a multi tenancy app which works perfectly. The app uses ActiveStorage and DigitalOceans Spaces to host images. I then use a custom domain to point to the subdomains.

```
customdomain.com >> forwards to >> tenant.domain.com
```

When I goto `tenant.domain.com` all of the images show up. Perfect.

The problem is when I go to `customdomain.com` only some images are appearing. If I refresh the page some of those images might reappear and others that were showing might break.

It's like there's a resource problem or lack of RAM maybe.. I don't know, seems weird that it works on the public domain and only breaks when using the custom domain.

The inspector shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

but if you copy the referenced url in the error the images shows up fine

***EDIT***

Ok so after looking at the inspector again I have noticed that some of the images  are being loaded from local active storage and others from digital ocean spaces. The ones from local active storage are broken.

New question.. Why are they loading from local storage at all.. my production.rb states: `config.active_storage.service = :amazon`